# Align numbers with and without comma with dcolumn

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, dcolumn

I am trying to align the values in the following regression output table by the 1000-euro-mark (the comma). However, there are also values below 1000 euros which are not aligned as I would like them to be (to the right of the commas above and below them). Is there a way to align them together with the rest despite those values lacking a comma?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{,}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} \centering
\caption{Regression Results}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{d{3.6}} }
\toprule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{Groups}   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$1^{st}$} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$1^{st}$} \\
\midrule
Intercept       & -32,332       & -66,459^{***} \\
                & (17,820)      & (21,006) \\ 
Income          & 340           & 870^{*} \\
                & (240)         & (340) \\
Experience      & 747^{*}       & 818 \\
                & (372)         & (469) \\
HH Type         & 5,984         & 24,189 \\
                & (12,499)      & (15,894) \\
\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{l}{R$^{2}$}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.07}    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{0.20} \\
\multicolumn{1}{l}{N}         & \multicolumn{1}{c}{299}     & \multicolumn{1}{c}{299} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up is not perfectly clear. Please clarify the purpose of the comma symbol: is it a decimal marker or a thousands-separator? If it’s intended to be the latter, you’d be misusing the machinery of the `dcolumn` package. Please advise.

Comment: From "by the 1000-euro-mark" I deduce that the comma is a thousands-separator. To achieve the desired alignment, you might want to use the `siunitx` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion using the `siunitx` package in order to align the numbers:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption, dcolumn}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{,}{,}{#1}}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
    group-digits             = true,
    group-minimum-digits     = 4,
    group-separator          = {,},
    table-align-text-pre     = false,
    table-align-text-post    = false,
    input-open-uncertainty   = ,
    input-close-uncertainty  = ,
    table-space-text-post    = $^{***}$,
    table-space-text-pre     = {(},
}
\begin{document}


\begin{table} \centering
\caption{Regression Results}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=-5]} }
\toprule
Groups          & {$1^{st}$}   & {$1^{st}$} \\
\midrule
Intercept       & -32332       & -66459$^{***}$ \\
                & (17820)      & (21006) \\ 
Income          & 340          & 870$^{*}$\\
                & (240)        & (340) \\
Experience      & 747$^{*}$    & 818 \\
                & (372)        & (469) \\
HH Type         & 5984         & 24189 \\
                & (12499)      & (15894) \\
\midrule
R$^{2}$         & {0.07}       & {0.20}\\
N               & {299}        & {299} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Please note that I manuallr removed the thousand separators in the numbers in the table. If you want to keep them in your code, you might want to add `input-ignore={,},input-decimal-markers={.}` to the `\sisetup` command.